# Probability distributing ice cream satisfying the taste of each person.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Distributing randomly 5 vanilla ice-creams and 5 chocolate ice-creams to 10 people among which 3 prefer vanilla, 2 prefer chocolate and the others do not have preference, what is the probability that everyone has an ice-cream he likes?

Comment: Have you had any thoughts on a possible approach?

Comment: @Henry Look at my answer proposed below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the 3 vanilla and 2 chocolate ice-cream to each person who prefer them. We now have 2 vanilla and 3 chocolate ice-creams left to distribute among 5 persons who are indifferent. We can do this in $5 \choose 2$ or $5 \choose 3$ ways, depending on distributing the 2 vanilla or 3 chocolate ice-creams left among the 5 persons, leading to only one way to giving the other flavor.

The sample space would be $10 \choose 5$ ways in distributing the 10 ice-creams to these 5 persons. So the answer would be:

$$P = \frac{5 \choose 2}{10 \choose 5} $$

.

Comment: You have the correct answer, but I am not convinced by your words.  I think it might be better to say that the number of ways to distribute $5$ vanilla among $3$ people who like vanilla and $5$ people who are indifferent so that the $3$ all get vanilla is ${5 \choose 5-3}$; the chocolate must then go to the rest. So there are  ${5 \choose 2}$ successful distributions out of ${10 \choose 5 }$ equally likely possibilities and hence your result.

Comment: This may be because English is not my mother language and I have some difficulty in write my reasoning in this language. Nevertheless, your approach is indeed more clear and convincing than mine. So I believe it would be fair to have your answer in order to have it checked as the the right one.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the principle $P(A\wedge B)=P(A)\cdot P(B|A)$ several times: First the three vanilla amateurs and then the two chocolate amateurs each pick one of the left over sealed packages. The probability $P$ that they are all successful is given by
$$P={5\over10}\cdot{4\over9}\cdot{3\over8}\cdot{5\over7}\cdot{4\over6}={5\over126}\ .$$